# System.NullReferenceException While trying to set TextBox value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a ComboBox in my code, I am trying to get the value of the selected item and write it in a TextBlock. while running the code i get An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'. What am i doing wrong?This is my Design

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
           <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="First" IsSelected="True"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Second"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Third"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Name="comboResult"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

and this is my code

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb=(ComboBox)sender;
        ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)cb.SelectedItem;
        comboResult.Text = cbi.Content.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `IsSelected` property from the `ComboBoxItem` and it works. You can then set `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` after initialization. I'm not familiar with how XAML renders, but I think that it's triggering the `SelectionChanged` event before the `TextBlock` renders. This can be observed by using a `Grid` with columns rather than a `StackPanel`, and putting the `TextBlock` first in the XAML (but in a higher column than the `ComboBox`); it works just fine. Additionally, if you catch the `TextBlock`'s `Loaded` event, you can see that the `SelectionChanged` event is being hit first in your original code.

Comment: Well i just added this line of code ' if (comboResult == null) return;' as someone suggested and it's working well. But i do not really understand why is it working as i am not calling any method on the comboResult. Your solution works too.

Comment: @ImanMemarpour Yeah that would work. Yes, you're trying to set its `Text` property when `comboResult` is null. Hover over `comboResult` and you'll see it's null.